# Wordpress cannot find all media

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

After manually moving wordpress to another hosting, it can't find all the media (e.g. photos). I changed the old url in the database in `wp-opitions` to the new one and changed `wp-config` to connect to the new database.
The problem is that some images are showing up, and some wordpress can't find despite being in the same uploads directory.

[image: images not loading]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When migrating, it is not enough only to change the old url to the new one in the opitions table.
You need to change it in the whole database.
The images in the text are often set not by their ID, but simply by a link.

Try to install this plugin [Better search and replace](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) and replace the domain in all records through it.

If you have access to the old site and everything works there, try to install this plugin [duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) it will pack the entire site, with pictures and plugins settings and then do all the changes in the database.

Comment: I used plugin "Better search and replace" but nothing changed.

Comment: What are the url of the broken links now?

Comment: new.example.com -> thats url of new site, img has url scr http://new.example.com/wp-content/uploads/Plakat-Dz-Niepodleg-osci-2021.jpg. So it should work but wordpress cant find img

Comment: Can you go to your server in the folder wp-content/uploads/ and see if this picture is there ? Or was it lost in the transfer ?

Comment: I can't find the image in that folder, while I also can't find it on the old server, and yet the old server displays the image.

Comment: Look at the old server, where the pictures are still displayed, what is the link to the picture there ?

Comment: If you have access to the old site and everything works there, try to install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ it will pack the entire site, with pictures and settings plugins and then do itself all the changes in the database.